# Counting frequency of value in a column in a data frame in R not giving expected results

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two data frames, one small and the other one large. The sizes are below. Basically, I expect to see the value in a column along with it's frequency and I expect a much higher number in the larger data frame as opposed to the smaller one.

```
> length(smalldf$col1)
[1] 5377
> length(largedf$col1)
[1] 56016
```

Now, when I try to find the number of unique values in each of these, I get the following. Now, this result is not as expected, I'm certain that there are many more *new(unique)* values in the larger data frame as compared to the smaller one.

```
> length(unique(smalldf$col1))
[1] 4697
> length(unique(largedf$col1))
[1] 4698
```

If I print out the unique values, I get largedf having all the 4697 elements as smalldf plus NA at the end.

So, I tried printing the values in the larger data frame which are not part of the smaller data frame, but I just get all my columns with NA as it's value

```
> library('plyr')
> a1NotIna2 <- sqldf('SELECT * FROM largedf EXCEPT SELECT * FROM smalldf')
> a1NotIna2
```

Just gives me all my columns with NA against it

Finally, I try to find the frequency of each value in the large data frame. *I get the same result for both*

Comment: Can you check whether the NAs are characters or not ? `sum(is.na(largedf$col1))`

Comment: @akrun, I'm sorry I tried hard to provide a reproducible example but since I'm reading from a huge data file, I'm not able to. When I run the command, you asked me to, I get the number 50639. What does that mean?

Comment: It means there are 50639 NA values in that column.  So, in essence `56016-50639#[1] 5377` values

Comment: @akrun, I think it's something to do with the following command. The large data frame was created to find those rows from the total data set(data frame) where either the the 19th or 20th column contained a particular value, 4820. This is the command I used. Is there something wrong here?largedf = totaldataset[which(totaldataset[,c(19:20)] == "4280"),]. On the smaller data set, it works, because I look for the value 4820 in only the 19th column. and use something like smalldata = totaldataset[which(totaldataset[,19] == "4280 "),]. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: I think you can try `largedf <- totaldataset[totaldataset[,19]=='4280'|totaldataset[,20=='4280',]`.  If the columns are numeric, there is no need for quotes for `4280`

Comment: @akrun, thanks a lot, it worked. I should have done this, but try to cheat because I actually need to check from columns 19 to 43. Isn't there an easier way to do this without hardcoding from 19 all the way up to 43?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
largedf <- totaldataset[Reduce(`|`, lapply(totaldataset[19:43], 
                     function(x) x=='4280')), ]
```

Comment: it works :) thank you. For the benefit of future readers, you may add a missing right parenthesis. So, it would look like largedf <- totaldataset[Reduce(`|`, lapply(totaldataset[19:43], function(x) x=='4280')), ]

Comment: @IAMTubby Thanks for mentioning about the missing parenthesis.  Sorry, I didn't test the code :-)